# Resolve Nullness Error from checkerframework

Tags: java, checker-framework

I have some java code which looks like below

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

abstract class Foo {

  abstract @Nullable String getFoo();
  
  void foo() {
    if (getFoo() != null) {
      bar(getFoo());  
    }
  }
  
  void bar(String str) {
      str.charAt(1);
  }
}
```

Which gives me the error

```
Error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
   found   : @Initialized @Nullable String
   required: @Initialized @NonNull String
```

which is undestandable as `getFoo` as been decorated with `Nullable`.

can I prevent this without modifying the `bar` method ? both methods `getFoo` and `bar` are out of my control for modifications.
What are the solutions to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried changing `@Nullable` to `@NonNull`?

Comment: both methods `getFoo` and `bar` are out of my control for modifications, as both are from different libraries and I am using them in my project. The last resort is to write a wrapper around any of the class, I am looking for a solution other than that if possible.

Comment: You call getFoo() twice. If you called it once, stored the result, nullchecked it and then passed it to bar(), maybe that would work?

Comment: @Taschi yes that works thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Nullness Checker is correct that the given code might throw a NullPointerException, because `getFoo()` might return different values on different invocations.  You can express that `getFoo()` returns the same value on every invocation (on the same receiver) by using the [`@Deterministic`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/dataflow/qual/Deterministic.html) method annotation:

```java
import org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Deterministic;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

abstract class Foo {

  @Deterministic
  abstract @Nullable String getFoo();
  
  void foo() {
    if (getFoo() != null) {
      bar(getFoo());  
    }
  }
  
  void bar(String str) {
      str.charAt(1);
  }
}
```

This is discussed in the [Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#type-refinement-purity).

If you cannot directly add `@Deterministic` to a library, you can write a [stub file](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub) with that annotation and use it while type-checking your code.

Comment: I have a general rule. Never make an assumption that you don't need to make. It sometimes leads to unexpected behavior, which means bugs. When you call a method twice, you're not only assuming the method is deterministic, you're assuming it runs efficiently. This is usually a safe assumption, but not always. I've seen simple methods like this that I don't realize will cause it to hit the network each time. I avoid this practice, even when I've written the code that I'm calling. Somebody else will be maintaining my code, and may change it.